# Breaking the while in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that extract sata from the source.

The database in source is SQL Server, and I need to do incrementally and in batch.

I have a problem, currently my while is not breaking and my code is uploading the same records a lot of times once the while is running and it does not stop.

My code

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    SET @BATCH_COUNTER = 100000;  
    -- QUERY HERE
    SET @QUERY = (@INSERT +  char(13) + char(10) +
'SELECT 
,Id
,Code
,StartDate
,EndDate
' + @INSERT_INTO + '
FROM OPENQUERY ([' + @LINKED_SERVER + '],''SELECT 
SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@BATCH_COUNTER as NVARCHAR(50)) + ' 
''''' + @COUNTRY_CODE + ''''' as Id_company
,Id
,Code
,StartDate
,EndDate
FROM table
WHERE  createdDate <= ''''' + @END_DATE + '''''
AND modifiedDate > ''''' + @THRESHOLD + '''''
order by modifiedDate
'')' );

SET @count = 0
reexecute:
 
BEGIN TRANSACTION @table_name;
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC(@QUERY);

    SET @ROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
    SET @ROWCOUNT_GERAL = @ROWCOUNT_GERAL + @ROWCOUNT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @table_name;
    END

    IF @count < 3
    BEGIN
        SET @count = @count + 1
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00';
        GOTO reexecute
    END

    SET @PRINT_MSG = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    RAISERROR(@PRINT_MSG,16,1) WITH NOWAIT
    BREAK
    RETURN;
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION @table_name;
END

IF @ROWCOUNT < @BATCH_COUNTER 
    BREAK;

SET @PRINT_MSG = 'Just loaded: ' + CAST(@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(150))
RAISERROR(@PRINT_MSG,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
END
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire stored procedure, I'm already assuming several things when reading the code (i.e., `@INSERT`, etc.). Your break is never met because the `@@ROWCOUNT` is reset by the previous transaction statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. You may want to include your `COMMIT TRANSACTION` in your try block?

Comment: Why are you batching it if you are doing it all in one transaction? Doesn't seem much, point, the whole point of batching is to commit between batches. And why use dynamic SQL, you can just do `FROM LinkedServer...Yourtable WHERE`

Comment: You don't have any logic that actually advances your INSERT, so you execute same insert until the cows go home. You should probably use PAGING in form of OFFSET X ROWS FETCH NEXT Y ROWS. Or advance ENDdates etc. Also, please do some indentation, your code is hard to follow due to alignment of the statements

Comment: @JatinMorar can you explain? Thanks

Answer (score -2):

when you use 1=1 ، You have condition that is always true,so you can change (while 1=1 ) to (while @ROWCOUNT < @BATCH_COUNTER )

Comment: But there is a break statement using the sand condition... So that's not the cause